# Tring to create a sorting game and have run into trouble

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

`Here is what I want to achieve:
I have a list of 10 items in image format.
I need to understand, for each user that plays the game, their order of preference for the items.
I have a page with clickable images, each time displaying only 2.
In each comparison there is a winner and a loser.

The game starts by comparing items 1 and 2, the user clicks one item and both are added to and empty list, the selected item first and the other one second.
Then, for the rest of the items starting from 3, the item is compared to the the last image in the list (the current least favorite).
If it wins, it gets compared to the next least favorite, until it loses and then added to the list in the correct spot, one after the last image it lost to and one before the last image it beat.
If it loses it is added to the end of the list and the next image is played.

For example, I chose 2 over 1 so the list is [2,1], then 3 is played so 3 vs 1 is shown, I choose 1 over 3 and the list is now [2,1,3]. Next 4 is played so 4 vs 3 is shown, I choose 4 over 3 so now it is 1 vs 4, again I choose 4 so now it is 2 vs 4, now I choose 2 so the list is now [2,4,1,3]. I need to do this for 10 images. The numbers are the image IDs.

This is my current code using JS:

```
const images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let currentIndex = 0;
let result = [];

const bottomUpForm = document.getElementById("bottomUpForm");
const bottomUpTitle = document.getElementById("bottomUpTitle");

function generateImagePair() {
    if (currentIndex < images.length - 1) {
        const image1 = images[currentIndex];
        const image2 = images[currentIndex + 1];

        // Create a container div for the image pair
        const imagePairContainer = document.createElement("div");
        imagePairContainer.className = "choice-container";

        // Create image elements for the current pair
        const img1 = document.createElement("img");
        img1.src = `/images/obj${image1}.jpg`;
        img1.alt = `Image ${image1}`;
        img1.className = "choice-image";

        const img2 = document.createElement("img");
        img2.src = `/images/obj${image2}.jpg`;
        img2.alt = `Image ${image2}`;
        img2.className = "choice-image";

        // Add click event listeners to handle image selection
        img1.addEventListener("click", () => {
            handleImageSelection(image1, image2);
        });

        img2.addEventListener("click", () => {
            handleImageSelection(image2, image1);
        });

        // Append the images to the container div
        imagePairContainer.appendChild(img1);
        imagePairContainer.appendChild(img2);

        bottomUpForm.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous content
        bottomUpForm.appendChild(imagePairContainer);
    } else {
        // No more pairs to compare, display the winning order
        bottomUpTitle.innerHTML = "Result:";
        bottomUpForm.innerHTML = result.join(", ");
    }
}

function handleImageSelection(selectedId, unselectedId) {
    result.push(selectedId);

    // Move to the next pair
    currentIndex++;

    // Check if all pairs have been displayed
    if (currentIndex < images.length) {
        generateImagePair();
    } else {
        // Show the winning order at the end
        generateImagePair();
        alert("Final Result: " + result.join(", "));
    }

    // Show the current result after each selection
    alert("Current Result: " + result.join(", "));
}

// Initialize the game by generating the first pair
generateImagePair();
```

I have tried so many versions of this and nothing seems to work, I am lost..
`

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what the problem is. "Having trouble" and "I am lost" are too generic for what's considered on-topic for this site. Are you receiving an error? Are the results not what you expect?  Also, please clarify what your actual question is.

Comment: Please convert your code to a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and add the HTML so we can try it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.